# make animated slider go backwards (right to left) to simulate a countdown?

Tags: r, shiny, slider, countdown

I want to animate a shiny slider so that it goes backwards automatically when the play button is hit, from right to left. I can't find a way to do this. The slider would mimic a time countdown of 10 seconds, this is my current code, it goes the wrong way. I tried unsuccessfully to mess with the step, min, max, etc. Is it even possible?

```
library(shiny); library(shinyjs); library(shinyWidgets)
jscode <- "shinyjs.play = function() {$('.slider-animate-button').trigger('click');}"
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-grid-text, .irs-grid-pol, .irs-slider {visibility:hidden !important;}'))),
  h3("countdown"),
  sliderInput("countdown", label = "", width = '300px',min = 0, max = 10,value = 0, step = 0.1, post="secs",
              animate = animationOptions(interval = 50, playButton = "", pauseButton = "")),
  actionButton("start", "start"))
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  disable("slider")
  observeEvent(input$start, priority=10, {js$play()})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for your help..
[image]

**Note**: in fact the main problem is not so much that is goes the wrong way, but that it should start completed and finish empty, for a countdown!

Comment: this is the closest i got https://jsfiddle.net/javatmp/oyctL9pz/ but not very clear to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out a rather satisfactory solution combining two ideas:

1. the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54372185/3871924) from @phalteman that allows the text label to be counting backwards thanks to a sliderTextInput
2. since we can't make the slider starting from the right, at least we can make it look like the bar is diminishing (otherwise it would not make sense for a countdown). A CSS *trick* to make the slider appear like it's diminishing even though it's still increasing: I invert the colors of the slider bar with the color of the background, so what appears to be the bar is actually the empty background being consumed gradually (in red in the picture below).

css code to place instead in the `tags$head` section:

```
.irs-bar {
    height: 20px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    background: #CCC !important;
}

.irs-bar-edge {
    height: 20px !important;
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    background: #CCC !important;
}

.irs-line {
    height: 20px !important;
    border: 1px solid #FF5964 !important;
    background: #FF5964 !important;
}

.irs-single {
    background: #FF5964 !important;
}

.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-grid-text, .irs-grid-pol, .irs-slider {
    visibility:hidden !important;
}
```

The CSS stylesheet would be like this (I Added an *important* label because for some Reason the changes were not taken into account…?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could mimic the countdown by counting backward from 10 to 0 using `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput()` and specifying a descending order to the slider, rather than coding a slider that moves right to left.

```
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
         tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-grid-text, .irs-grid-pol, .irs-slider {visibility:hidden !important;}'))),
         h3("countdown"),
         sliderInput("countdown", label = "", width = '300px', min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 0.1, post="secs",
           animate = animationOptions(interval = 50, playButton = "", pauseButton = "")),
         shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput("countdown2", label = "", width = '300px', 
              choices = seq(from = 10, to = 0, by = -0.1), post="secs", 
              animate = animationOptions(interval = 50, playButton = "", pauseButton = "")),
         actionButton("start", "start")
      )
```

Not sure it achieves the same visual effect, but it might be an acceptable workaround...

Comment: This solution does have some funny behaviour right at the end of the countdown, counting down from 0.999999999 to 0 by 0.1 (i.e., 0.899999999, 0.79999999, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I thought, using a totally different approach, would be to use **.gif** image of the desired countdown.

I uploaded an example file of a 10sec gif created with ggplot2: https://ibb.co/tKQ4xps
The app would be like this, using a fix image when stopped :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(h3("countdown 10secs"),
                htmlOutput("display.image"),actionButton("start", "start"),actionButton("stop", "stop"))
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  image = reactiveValues(name="full.png")
  observeEvent(input$start, {image$name="gif_timer_10sec.gif"}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$stop, {image$name="full.png"}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  output$display.image <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste0("<center><img height=25 width=300 align=left src=", image$name, "></center>"))})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also post the basic code to generate the 100 images composing the gif:

```
for (i in 100:1) {
  g = ggplot() + theme(line = element_blank(),text = element_blank(),title = element_blank())
  png(paste0("plot_", 200-i, ".png"))
  g = g + geom_col(aes_string(x=1, y=i), fill="#FF5964") + xlim(0.5,1.5) + ylim(0,100) + coord_flip()
  print(g); dev.off()
}
```

The final app looks like this:

[image]